# New user roles typo3 neos

Tags: user-roles, neoscms

I need to add new user roles, such as "TYPO3.Neos:Creator"
Typo3-neos Currently supported roles:"TYPO3.Neos:Editor", "TYPO3.Neos:Administrator". How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but it seems available roles are not stored in database, but rather are gathered from yaml configuration files (and stored in cache??).

So, add a role in any `Policy.yaml` file, like:

```
roles:
  'My.Package:CreatorOfDoomRole':
    privileges: []
```

After that you can use the flow CLI command `./flow user:addrole <username> <role>` to add a new role to a user (the roles are stored as comma-separated list in table `typo3_flow_security_account`, field `roleidentifiers`).

(Some more info about how yaml is cached: "The yaml files are cached, in development context that cache should be purged on every request (and on master that's a bit optimized so they will only be flushed in development context if there was really a change to the yaml). Stored in file: Data/Temporary/Production/Configuration/ProductionConfigurations.php")